# Jquery Smooth Scroll To DIV - Using ID value from Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing

So i'm having some issues with my JQuery which is suppose to scroll to particular divs.

**HTML**

```
<div id="searchbycharacter">
    <a class="searchbychar" href="#" id="#0-9" onclick="return false">0-9 |</a> 
    <a class="searchbychar" href="#" id="#A" onclick="return false"> A |</a> 
    <a class="searchbychar" href="#" id="#B" onclick="return false"> B |</a> 
    <a class="searchbychar" href="#" id="#C" onclick="return false"> C |</a> 
    ... Untill Z
</div>

<div id="0-9">
    <p>some content</p>
</div>

<div id="A">
    <p>some content</p>
</div>

<div id="B">
    <p>some content</p>
</div>

<div id="C">
    <p>some content</p>
</div>

... Untill Z
```

**JQuery**

What i want the code to do is: On click event of an .searchbychar A TAG > Take the ID attributes value and scroll to that...

```
$( '.searchbychar' ).click(function() {

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.searchbychar').attr('id').offset().top
    }, 2000);

});
```

Comment: Take the hashes from the id

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Ids are meant to be unique, and never use an id that starts with a number, use data-attributes instead to set the target like so :

```
<div id="searchbycharacter">
    <a class="searchbychar" href="#" data-target="numeric">0-9 |</a> 
    <a class="searchbychar" href="#" data-target="A"> A |</a> 
    <a class="searchbychar" href="#" data-target="B"> B |</a> 
    <a class="searchbychar" href="#" data-target="C"> C |</a> 
    ... Untill Z
</div>
```

As for the jquery :

```
$(document).on('click','.searchbychar', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = "#" + this.getAttribute('data-target');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: @JackWilliams didn't notice he had it there O.o is it even good practice ?

Comment: @JackWilliams can you add a console.log(this.id)

Comment: @JackWilliams disregard the edit was a brain fart moment, a/w let's debug this, add a console.log(this.id) after event.preventDefault()

Comment: For DRYer coding, you should use `event.stopPropagation()` in addition to `event.preventDefault()` in your jQuery. That accomplishes the same thing as `onclick="return false"`. Awesome solution though!!

Comment: I forgot about the return false :-P prevent default deals with that will edit once home

Comment: Thank you , it is helpful .

Comment: i did the same but got an error like that "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"... what is the solution for this any idea ?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
$('.searchbychar').click(function () {
    var divID = '#' + this.id;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(divID).offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

F.Y.I.

- You need to prefix a class name with a `.` (**dot**) like in your first line of code.
- `$( 'searchbychar' ).click(function() {`
- Also, your code `$('.searchbychar').attr('id')` will return a string ID not a jQuery object. Hence, you can not apply `.offset()` method to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy... Your explaination helped me here... Thanks a tonnnnnnnnn......

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

```
<!-- jquery smooth scroll to id's -->   
<script>
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

With just this snippet you can use an unlimited number of hash-links and corresponding ids without having to execute a new script for each.

I already explained how it works in another thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28631803/4566435 (or here's a [direct link to my blog post](http://bibiano.io/jquery-smooth-scroll/))

For clarifications, let me know. Hope it helps!