# Smooth scroll to div id jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I've been trying to get a scroll to div id jquery code to work correctly. Based on another stack overflow question i tried the following

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/8tLdq/

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
   $.scrollTo($('#myDiv'), 1000);
});
```

But it didn't work. It just snaps to the div. I also tried

```
$('#myButton').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
   $.scrollTo($('#myDiv'), 1000);
});
```

With no progress.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432656/scroll-to-a-div-using-jquery

Comment: @TheVanillaThrilla I did but it seemed too bloated for a single link use

Comment: @StevenPHP, I have replaced JavaScript code in your example in accordance with my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26129950/947687. And it works http://jsfiddle.net/8tLdq/643/.

Comment: Can be done in **Plain JS**  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61918221/741251

Comment: Both JS and jQuery Solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70536673/2993242

Answer (score 847, accepted):

You need to animate the `html, body`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/8tLdq/1/

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: @vector I have one issue, once it's clicked I have to fight with jquery to scroll up,  any solution?

Comment: @yesitsme ...up or down in my case

Comment: @GraySpectrum up, only right after clicking, sounds like there's a delay.

Comment: I have the same question, what if i have few buttons that need to scroll to different locations, tried modifying this code but it does not work. Could you please provide another example?

Comment: Found some "fix" for it. Scrolling of the **proper element** is now fixed, but still it goes up and down by clicking on same "scroll-to" target: `var target = $(this).data("target"); $(".basics-content").animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top}, 1000); });` Explanation: `.basics-content` is the inner div of the modal which I actually want to scroll to, with `target` I provide the id number of the element ...

Comment: ... like: `data-target="#jump_xx_yy` and then the targeted element: `<div id="jump_xx_yy">`.

Comment: i did the same but i got this error " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined" so what's the meaning of this can you help me...?

Answer (score 131):

If you want to override standard **href-id navigation** on the page without changing the HTML markup for **smooth scrolling**, use this ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/1eamwt4e/)):

```
// handle links with @href started with '#' only
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(e) {
    // target element id
    var id = $(this).attr('href');

    // target element
    var $id = $(id);
    if ($id.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    // prevent standard hash navigation (avoid blinking in IE)
    e.preventDefault();

    // top position relative to the document
    var pos = $id.offset().top;

    // animated top scrolling
    $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: pos});
});
```

Comment: This works well, may I suggest a very small tweak `var pos = $(id).offset().top;` can be `var pos = $id.offset().top;`

Comment: Very nice. If you only want this to happen on certain links (say you have some to show or hide information), just add a class name to them and tack your class name (say scroller) to the end of the match declaration ( e.g. a[href^="#"].scroller ).

Comment: How do you do that without jQuery?

Answer (score 30):

here is my 2 cents:

Javascript:

```
$('.scroll').click(function() {
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: eval($('#' + $(this).attr('target')).offset().top - 70)
    }, 1000);
});
```

Html:

```
<a class="scroll" target="contact">Contact</a>
```

and the target:

```
<h2 id="contact">Contact</h2>
```

Comment: This seams to work only if you don't declare doctype.

Comment: What is the use of `eval` here for?

Comment: I think it is required `$('html, body').animate` to Scroll

Answer (score 19):

## Plain JS:

#### Can be done in plain JS if you use modern browsers.

```js
document
    .getElementById("range-calculator")
    .scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
```

Browser support is a bit issue, but [modern browsers support it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

Comment: Safari on iOS doesn't support this

Comment: Usual suspects. Safari on desktop also doesn't support it (according to MDN)

Comment: I have just tried safari desktop, and it is now working.

Comment: I looked at several similar questions and this answer (using ...`.scrollIIntoView(`...`)`) is the only one that worked for me on a non-scrolling page with targets loaded within a scrolling div (Chrome 102.0.5005.61 (Official Build) (arm64))

Answer (score 16):

**My solution for both Vanilla JS and jQuery**

**Vanilla JS:**

```
document
    .querySelector("#myDiv")
    .scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
```

**jQuery:**

You need to animate the html, body

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Other properties of `scroll-behavior`

```
scroll-behavior: auto|smooth|initial|inherit;
```

Answer (score 12):

one example more:

HTML link:

```
<a href="#featured" class="scrollTo">Learn More</a>
```

JS:

```
  $(".scrollTo").on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var target = $(this).attr('href');
     $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: ($(target).offset().top)
     }, 2000);
  });
```

HTML anchor:

```
  <div id="featured">My content here</div>
```

Comment: Earlier it was not scrolling to the top of the div, but then I made the below-mentioned changes and it worked.

scrollTop: ($(target).offset().top - 120)

Answer (score 8):

This code will be useful for any internal link on the web

```
    $("[href^='#']").click(function() {
        id=$(this).attr("href")
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(id).offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's what I use:

```
<!-- jquery smooth scroll to id's -->   
<script>
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

The beauty with this one is you can use an unlimited number of hash-links and corresponding ids without having to execute a new script for each.

If you’re using WordPress, insert the code in your theme’s `footer.php` file right before the closing body tag `</body>`.

If you have no access to the theme files, you can embed the code right inside the post/page editor (you must be editing the post in Text mode) or on a Text widget that will load up on all pages.

If you’re using any other CMS or just HTML, you can insert the code in a section that loads up on all pages right before the closing body tag `</body>`.

If you need more details on this, check out my quick post here: [jQuery smooth scroll to id](http://bibiano.io/jquery-smooth-scroll/)

Hope that helps, and let me know if you have questions about it.

Comment: Loving how simple and vanilla this is, perfect.

Answer (score 5):

are you sure you are loading the jQuery scrollTo Plugin file?

you might be getting a object: method not found "scrollTo" error in the console.

the scrollTO method is not a native jquery method. to use it you need to include the jquery scroll To plugin file.

ref: 
http://flesler.blogspot.in/2009/05/jqueryscrollto-142-released.html
http://flesler.blogspot.in/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

soln: 
add this in the head section.

```
<script src="\\path\to\the\jquery.scrollTo.js file"></script>
```

Comment: This should've been the accepted answer. The code in the question is correct, and works fine. It looks as though the scrollTo plugin isn't/wasn't working. . .He didn't ask about different ways to do something similar.

Answer (score 4):

This script is a improvement of the script from Vector. I have made a little change to it. So this script works for every link with the class page-scroll in it.

At first without easing:

```
$("a.page-scroll").click(function() {
    var targetDiv = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(targetDiv).offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

For easing you will need Jquery UI:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Add this to the script:

```
'easeOutExpo'
```

Final

```
$("a.page-scroll").click(function() {
    var targetDiv = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(targetDiv).offset().top
    }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');
});
```

All the easings you can find here: [Cheat Sheet](http://easings.net/).

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest.Source-https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp

```
var elmnt = document.getElementById("content");
elmnt.scrollIntoView();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution to smooth scroll to div / anchor using jQuery in case you have a fixed header so that it doesn't scroll underneath it. 
Also it works if you link it from other page.

Just replace ".site-header" to div that contains your header.

```
$(function() {

$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
var headerheight = $(".site-header").outerHeight();
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

  if (target.length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: (target.offset().top - headerheight)
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
}
});

//Executed on page load with URL containing an anchor tag.
if($(location.href.split("#")[1])) {
var headerheight = $(".site-header").outerHeight();
  var target = $('#'+location.href.split("#")[1]);
  if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top - headerheight
    }, 1);
    return false;
  }
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using the following simple jQuery code.

Tutorial, Demo, and Source code can be found from here - [Smooth scroll to div using jQuery](http://www.codexworld.com/smooth-scroll-to-div-using-jquery/)

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.substr(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#section1">Go Section 1</a>
<div id="section1">
    <!-- Content goes here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I tried this, that work great for me.

```
$('a[href*="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 500, 'linear');
});
```

HTML:

```
 <a href="#fast-food" class="active" data-toggle="tab" >FAST FOOD</a>

<div id="fast-food">
<p> Scroll Here... </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: What is different in your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

This works to me.

```
<div id="demo">
        <h2>Demo</h2>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Handler for .ready() called.
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#demo').offset().top
        }, 'slow');
    });
</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Question is JQuery. Simplest should be below code. Make sure you include JQueryUI. Replace {version} with the latest version and off course here is the list for all methods you can use for animation. easeOutExpo with 2 seconds would give you very artistic scrolling.

Linear, swing, easeOutQuad, easeInQuad, easeInOutQuad, easeOutCubic, easeInCubic, easeInOutCubic, easeOutQuart, easeInQuart, easeInOutQuart, easeOutQuint, easeInQuint, easeInOutQunit, **easeOutExpo**, easeInExpo, easeInOutExpo, easeOutSine, easeInSine, easeInOutSine, easeOutCirc, easeInCirc, easeInOutCirc, easeOutElastic, easeInElastic, easeInOutElastic, easeOutBack, easeInBack, easeInOutBack, easeOutBounce, easeInBounce, easeInOutBounce

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/{version}/jquery-ui.js"></script>

$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#id").offset().top }, 1000, "easeInExpo");
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest javascript worked absolutely perfectly.

```
$('CLASS OR ID').on("click", function() {
        scrollTo($('#TARGETED CLASS OR ID / DIV'), 1000);
     });
```