# Is there a way to target a specific Tumblr post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr

I am attempting to add an animated scroll to my Tumblr and I have found one in this question: [Smooth scroll to div id jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012495/smooth-scroll-to-div-id-jquery). But the trick is, I need the button to jump to a specific post on the Tumblr.

I have found that each post has a specific id called `PostID`, and I have located the specific `PostID` I need. What I cannot find is an actual use of the `PostID` in the HTML, so I do not know how to target it. I tried:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("post-{130746374784}").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

But I am sure I am calling it wrong. Can anyone tell me how to target it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The simple preamble

As pointed out by [@approxiblue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/880772/approxiblue) in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017973/is-there-a-way-to-target-a-specific-tumblr-post/33020592#comment54002433_33020592), Tumblr offers a variety of [variables](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#basic_variables) that can be used in a theme, including `PostID`.

It would therefore be possible to replace something like this:

```
<div class="post photo">
    <!-- more HTML here -->
</div>
```

With something like this:

```
<div class="post photo" id="myPost_{PostID}">
    <!-- more HTML here -->
</div>
```

Allowing a more direct targeting of the post, as such:

```
var post = $('#myPost_129129898812');
```

### The long answer

Observing a Tumblr page, it seems the `PostID` is only available in links. This means we have to find the link including the `PostID`, then go back up to its container `div`.

This is an example of a Tumblr post on a homepage:

```
<!-- PHOTO POST 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
<div class="post photo">
    <div class="wide">
        <a href="http://stolenjokescomic.tumblr.com/image/129129898812">
        <img src="http://41.media.tumblr.com/16c2f56a9f739889fbd4896f8524907c/tumblr_nupf28wgLl1toph1no1_1280.png" alt="" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="narrow">
        <div class="metadata">
            <div class="date">
                <a href="http://stolenjokescomic.tumblr.com/post/129129898812">Sep. 15 2015</a>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- metadata end -->
    </div> <!-- narrow end -->
</div> <!-- post end -->
```

We will:

1. Target the element with class `post`
2. Target the child with class `date`
3. Target the child link with attribute `href` containing `post/129129898812`, which is the `PostID` used in this example
4. Go back up by targeting the parent with class `post` using [`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)
5. Get the position

Code:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    var position = $('.post .date a[href*="post/129129898812"]')
        .parents('.post')
        .offset().top;

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: position
    }, 2000);
});
```

You can try it out by:

1. Going to [stolenjokescomic](http://stolenjokescomic.tumblr.com/)
2. Opening a scratchpad (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> in Firefox)
3. Pasting this code:

   ```
   $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $('.post .date a[href*="post/129129898812"]')
           .parents('.post').offset().top
   }, 2000);
   ```
4. Running it (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in Firefox)

The page should scroll down to the post. Unless you read this in a few months and the post is not on the homepage anymore.

### Alternative for the OKMove theme

1. Get the target element using the `PostID`.
2. Get the index of the target within the list of posts.
3. Get the element to which the `zoomIn` function is attached.
4. Trigger the click event to call the `zoomIn` function as many times as necessary to reach the target.

Code:

```
var zoomIn = $('.zoom-in');
var target = $('#content section .about a[href*="post/18629325910"]').parents('section');
var id     = $('#content section').index(target[0]);

for(var i=0; i<id; ++i) {
    zoomIn.click();
}
```

You can try out this code on [OKMove](http://okmove.tumblr.com/) using a scratchpad.

If this goes too fast, we can adjust using a a recursive `setTimeout`:

```
var zoomIn = $('.zoom-in');
var target = $('#content section .about a[href*="post/18629325910"]').parents('section');
var index  = $('#content section').index(target[0]);

var count = 0;
var weNeedToGoDeeper = function() {

    if(count < index) {
       zoomIn.click();
       setTimeout(weNeedToGoDeeper, 400);
    }

    ++count;
};

weNeedToGoDeeper();
```

We can expand this further to work from any position, analyzing the current position by parsing the `transform` property and then decide which way to zoom and how many times to do so by calculating the relative position between where we are and where we want to go:

```
function parseMatrix(s) {
    return (
        s.match(/^matrix3d.(.*).$/) || ['', '0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0']
    )[1].split(', ');
}

var zoomIn  = $('.zoom-in');
var zoomOut = $('.zoom-out');
var content = $('#content');
var target  = $('#content section .about a[href*="post/18629325910"]').parents('section');
var index   = $('#content section').index(target[0]);

var pos = parseMatrix(pos = content.css('transform'))[14];

pos = Math.round(pos/1000);
pos = index - pos;

var zoomElem = pos <= 0 ? zoomOut : zoomIn;

pos = Math.abs(pos);

for(var i=0; i<pos; ++i) {
    zoomElem.click();
}
```

Comment: First of all thankyou so much for this detailed break down. Now I understand how you approached this. However I did try the code and replaced the id number with mine on my tumblr, it is still not responding. At this point I do not even know if the issue is fundamentally with the scroll code or anything else.

I am using a theme called okmove (okmove.tumblr.com) , which already has an inbulit script that creates an interesting scroll effect. Could this be a problem of conflict? Originally I thought it would not clash as the browser scroll is not affected.

Comment: @DaHao I'll need to test that.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not have their code. Is it possible to use their site to scratchpad it?

Comment: @DaHao I've been trying things already, got a few ideas but it's more complex than a regular page.

Comment: I see..would it be possible if we targeted specific percentage of the scroll bar? My tumblr posts are fixed. There will be no new posts. So I can confirm the % mark of the bar for each post. would tht be easier?

Comment: @DaHao That may be indeed considerably easier. I'm putting that on the list of things to test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91859/discussion-between-da-hao-and-spenibus).

Comment: @DaHao I updated with a solution for OKMove. It should work in a fairly *standard* way rather than being too specific.

Comment: Alright, now I got it to work on my tumblr via scratchpad, however, when I try to insert the code into my button code, it does not work. Would you teach me how to implement this script as a button? Almost there!

Comment: @DaHao Get in the chat above, comments might be a bit tedious for that.

Comment: Instead of grabbing the post ID from the link, you can change the theme code and use the variable [`{PostID}`](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#posts) to output the post ID wherever you need.

Comment: @approxiblue That does sound better. Clearly a trick to make me read more documentation.