# How to smooth scroll to div id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to set a div that I want to scroll to when I click a div in my menu. The problem is that the scroll to the div, is not scrolling to the div that I have in my code, It always scroll to something else on my page, strange.
Im using the code bellow:

```
$(".dns-anchor").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#dns-scroll").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

ID #dns-scroll is the div that I want to scroll to.

Comment: A little more code would be helpful, specially the html you are using.

Comment: It works fine for me. (https://jsfiddle.net/og45xxe0/1/)

Comment: Do you maybe have more elements with id 'dns-scroll' because then it will go to the first one I guess. Can you send your whole code?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**or**

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

**Please check this link:-[Smooth scroll to div id jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012495/smooth-scroll-to-div-id-jquery)**

Comment: Your second example is exactly like in the question.