# How to get window exact scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to activate menu for every sections (when scroll reached to that element position). But, i found the last section (contact section) is not activated, while the scroll is reached to end. How to resolve this and if any possible way to get scroll exact position (which means the scroll top and sections top is equal value). See [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f99L0ssp/25)

```js
var scrollLink = $(".scroll");
 scrollLink.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var scroll_linkPosition = $(this.hash).offset().top - 70;

  $("body, html").animate({
   scrollTop: scroll_linkPosition
  }, 1000);
 });

 $(document).scroll(function() {
  var scroll_position = $(document).scrollTop();
    console.log(scroll_position);
  
  scrollLink.each(function() {
   var sectionOffsetTop = $(this.hash).offset().top - 70;
   
   if(sectionOffsetTop <= scroll_position) {
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    $(this.hash).addClass("active");
   }
  }, 1000);
 });
```

```css
/*----*/
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 21px;
}
.container {
 max-width: 1170px;
 margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 10px
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.clearfix::before, .clearfix::after {
 display: table;
 content: "";
}
.clearfix::after {
 clear: both;
}
header {
    background: #f6f6f6;
    padding: 20px 0;
    line-height: 31px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.header_innrWrapper {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.logo {
    float: left;
}
.logo a {
 font-size: 27px;
 color: #333;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
}
ul {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
ul li {
 list-style-type: none;
}

.header_innrWrapper ul {
 float: right;
}
.header_innrWrapper ul li {
    float: left;
 min-width: 70px;
    text-align: center;
 margin-left: 2px;
}
.header_innrWrapper ul li.active a {
 background: #3f3d48;
 color: #fff;
}
.header_innrWrapper ul li a {
 display: block;
 color: #464646;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.wrapper {
    padding-top: 70px;
}
.wrapper_article {
    padding: 40px 20px;
}
.wrapper_article h2 {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.wrapper_article p {
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.wrapper_article p.no-mar {
 margin: 0 !important;
}
#home {
    background: #b0deff;
}
#about {
    background: #fff58a;
}
#service {
    background: #5bff50;
}
#feature {
    background: #ffb4bb;
}
#contact {
    background: #fff58a;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 700px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="header_innrWrapper clearfix">
     <div class="logo"><a href="#">Logo</a></div>
     <ul class="clearfix">
      <li class="active"><a class="nav_anchor scroll" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_anchor scroll" href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_anchor scroll" href="#service">Service</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_anchor scroll" href="#feature">Feature</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_anchor scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
   <section class="wrapper">
    <div id="home" class="wrapper_article">
     <h2>Home Section</h2>
     
     <p>Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.</p>
     <p class="no-mar">Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="about" class="wrapper_article">
     <h2>About Section</h2>
     
     <p>Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.</p>
     <p class="no-mar">Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="service" class="wrapper_article">
     <h2>Service Section</h2>
     
     <p>Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.</p>
     <p class="no-mar">Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="feature" class="wrapper_article">
     <h2>Feature Section</h2>
     
     <p>Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.</p>
     <p>Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.</p>
     <p class="no-mar">Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contact" class="wrapper_article">
     <h2>Contact Section</h2>
     
     <p>Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     </p>
     
    </div>
   </section>
  </div>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: See the listed code: https://jsfiddle.net/f99L0ssp/25/

Comment: Please include your code in the actual question though. External code can always get lost.

Comment: Because your page height is shorter than that this condition `if(sectionOffsetTop <= scroll_position)` satisfies. You need to check for this situation too.

Comment: That is fine. But i need to find the exact scroll top position? If possible let me know.

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481350/how-to-get-scrollbar-position-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
check this updated code:
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f99L0ssp/31/

```
changes made are:

    #contact {
        background: #fff58a;
        padding-bottom: 300px;                               //added this line
    }

    var sectionOffsetTop = $(this.hash).offset().top - 80;   //changed from 70 to 80
```

Answer (score 0):

Scroll to a div starting

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

[Smooth scroll to div id jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012495/smooth-scroll-to-div-id-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

here is test

```js
 var $win = $("html");
var scrollLink = $(".scroll");
 scrollLink.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var scroll_linkPosition = $(this.hash).offset().top - 70;
    $win.animate({
   scrollTop: scroll_linkPosition
  }, 1000);
 });

 $(document).scroll(function() {
  var scroll_position = $(document).scrollTop();
   
  
  scrollLink.each(function() {
   var sectionOffsetTop = $(this.hash).offset().top - 80;
      var docDiff = 718; // fix for last div
   if(sectionOffsetTop <= scroll_position || ($win.scrollTop() + docDiff >= $(document).height())) {
       
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    $(this.hash).addClass("active");
   }
  }, 1000);
 });
```

```css
/*----*/
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 21px;
}
.container {
 max-width: 1170px;
 margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 10px
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.clearfix::before, .clearfix::after {
 display: table;
 content: "";
}
.clearfix::after {
 clear: both;
}
header {
    background: #f6f6f6;
    padding: 20px 0;
    line-height: 31px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.header_innrWrapper {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.logo {
    float: left;
}
.logo a {
 font-size: 27px;
 color: #333;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
}
ul {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
ul li {
 list-style-type: none;
}

.header_innrWrapper ul {
 float: right;
}
.header_innrWrapper ul li {
    float: left;
 min-width: 70px;
    text-align: center;
 margin-left: 2px;
}
.header_innrWrapper ul li.active a {
 background: #3f3d48;
 color: #fff;
}
.header_innrWrapper ul li a {
 display: block;
 color: #464646;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.wrapper {
    padding-top: 70px;
}
.wrapper_article {
    padding: 40px 20px;
}
.wrapper_article h2 {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.wrapper_article p {
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.wrapper_article p.no-mar {
 margin: 0 !important;
}
#home {
    background: #b0deff;
}
#about {
    background: #fff58a;
}
#service {
    background: #5bff50;
}
#feature {
    background: #ffb4bb;
}
#contact {
    background: #fff58a;
    padding-bottom: 300px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 700px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="header_innrWrapper clearfix">
     <div class="logo"><a href="#">Logo</a></div>
     <ul class="clearfix">
      <li class="active"><a class="nav_anchor scroll" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_anchor scroll" href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_anchor scroll" href="#service">Service</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_anchor scroll" href="#feature">Feature</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_anchor scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
   <section class="wrapper">
    <div id="home" class="wrapper_article">
     <h2>Home Section</h2>
     
     <p>Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.</p>
     <p class="no-mar">Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="about" class="wrapper_article">
     <h2>About Section</h2>
     
     <p>Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.</p>
     <p class="no-mar">Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="service" class="wrapper_article">
     <h2>Service Section</h2>
     
     <p>Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.</p>
     <p class="no-mar">Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="feature" class="wrapper_article">
     <h2>Feature Section</h2>
     
     <p>Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.</p>
     <p>Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.</p>
     <p class="no-mar">Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contact" class="wrapper_article">
     <h2>Contact Section</h2>
     
     <p>Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     Creating custom graphics with a real wow factor requires a suite of essential tools that can be a real difference maker for a fast and easy creation of visual content without any design experience.
     </p>
     
    </div>
   </section>
  </div>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thats fine. But, i need exact position of the scroll top. There is any possible to find?