# Smooth Scroll Specific Links on One Page Website with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to smooth scroll from Nav to container ID and the page is scrolling. However, I have a bootstrap "list-group" that also uses href and id in a container. When I click on the href in the list-group it smooth scrolls and bugs out. Is there a way to smooth scroll SPECIFIC Id's just for the nav and block the list-group from reacting to the JS?

I have tried this and it doesn't seem to work [smooth scroll to div with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012495/smooth-scroll-to-div-id-jquery)

tried `html { scroll-behavior: smooth;}` but not compatible on all browsers

Using this code and it's working but bugging out [how css smooth scroll jquery](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_smooth_scroll_jquery)

Link to the index.html for this website with `.js` in body: [index.html](https://github.com/azza74/onepagewebsite/blob/master/index.html)

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two routes to avoid triggering smooth scroll on links other than the list-group.

1) the route you suggested by applying this functionality to the nav only:

```
$('a.nav-link').on('click', function(event) {
    ...
})
```

2) apply to all links **excluding** list group items:

```
$('a').not('[data-toggle]').on('click', function(event) {
    ...
})
```