# Getting src code for a section directly with requests in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to **get the source code only of a section from website** instead of whole page and then parsing out the section, as it **will be faster than loading whole page and then parsing**. I tried passing the section link as url parameter but still getting whole page.

```
 url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012495/smooth-scroll-to-div-id-jquery/#answer-19013712'
 response = requests.get(url)
 print(response.text)
```

Comment: Not possible, HTTP(S) protocol does not allow that.

Comment: The server sends you the whole html file anyway, if you have control over the server, then you can use query params to pre-filter the html file before it's sent at the server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get specific section directly with requests api, but you can use `beautifulsoup` for that purpose.
A small sample is given by dataquest [website](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-tutorial-python/):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
page = requests.get("http://dataquestio.github.io/web-scraping-pages/ids_and_classes.html")

page.content
```

Running the above script will output this html String.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A simple example page
</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p class="inner-text first-item" id="first">
First paragraph.
</p><p class="inner-text">
Second paragraph.
</p></div>
<p class="outer-text first-item" id="second"><b>
First outer paragraph.
</b></p><p class="outer-text"><b>
Second outer paragraph.
</b>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

You can get specific section by finding it through tag type, class or id.

By tag-type:

```
soup.find_all('p')
```

By class:

```
soup.find_all('p', class_='outer-text')
```

By Id:

```
soup.find_all(id="first")
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS will not allow you to do that.

You can use the [Stackoverflow API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids) instead. You can pass the answer id 19013712. And thus only get that specific answer via the API.

Note, you may still have to [register for an APP key](https://stackapps.com/users/login?returnurl=/apps/oauth/register)

Comment: I want to use the concept at some other place, which don't have any API. In the ques, I stated stackoverflow for example case only.