# jQuery Automatically Scroll the Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar

Is there any way that I can trigger scroll down and scroll up of a scroll bar at any HTML element with jQuery?

There are some divs at my page and I want to scroll down/up one of thems scrollbar with jQuery.

Comment: You can change the `scrollTop` property, which is what scrolling does.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831970/jquery-smooth-scroll-to-div-using-id-value-from-link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right then maybe you want to scroll inside the divs.

Here's the example :

http://jsfiddle.net/fxj4jonx/1/

The basic code :

```
$("#your_div_to_scroll_into").animate({scrollTop:[scroll amount]},[scroll time]);
```

```js
$("#sDiv1").click(function(){
$("#div1").animate({ scrollTop: 1000 }, 3000);
});


$("#sDiv2").click(function(){
$("#div2").animate({ scrollTop: 500 }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Scroll Div1" id="sDiv1"/>
<input type="button" value="Scroll Div2" id="sDiv2"/>
<br/>
<hr/>

Div 1
<div id='div1' style='height:100px; overflow:scroll; width:200px;align:left;'>
    text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>
</div>
<br/>
<hr/>

Div 2
<div id='div2' style='height:100px; overflow:scroll; width:200px; align:left;'>
    text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is want you want:

```
$("#button").click(function (){$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#ScrolltothisID").offset().top}, 500 <-- time in MS);});
```

If you click on a element with the id #button it will scroll down to #ScrolltothisID

Answer (score 0):

Check the JSFiddle :- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6nw74sz/1/)

```
$(document).on('click','.searchByDiv', function(event) {
var targetDiv = "#" + this.getAttribute('data-target');
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(targetDiv).offset().top
}, 1000);
});
```